# Rename Field Name to Illegal Name & Output to .fac file

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day

I have a table of the following format:

```
Heading1   Heading2   Heading3
Data1      Data2      Data3
```

Current VBA code used to output table to a comma delimited text file:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Table", "C:\Output.txt", True
```

I require the table to be output to a comma delimited ".fac" file which is a file type unique to an application called "Prophet". I am unable to do this using the current code. If I change ".txt" to ".fac", Access produces the following error: "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

I also require "Heading1" to be changed to "!2". I cannot change "Heading1" to be "!2" in Datasheet view since special characters are not allowed in the headings of tables within Access.

Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Josh

Comment: If you export to `.txt` and later rename that file as `.fac`, would that solve the first issue?

Comment: Hi @HansUp, yes that would solve the first issue

Comment: `Name "C:\Output.txt" As "C:\Output.fac"`

Comment: Great, thanks! That fixes the first issue. Any ideas on how to produce the "!2" in the first cell of the table?

Comment: No.   That's why I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: Might be a bit clunky, but you could open xl app through access vba, open the file you've just saved change cell a1 then save and close the book (don't forget to close app and set to nothing)